# Brownian Motions and Martingales

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, martingales

> State whether each of the statement is true or false.
>
> - If $Z$ is a standard normal random variable then $X_t = Z\sqrt t$ is a Brownian motion.
> - If $W_t$ and $W_t'$  are two independent Brownian motions and $\rho$ is a fixed constant such that $|\rho|<1$, then $X_t = \rho W_t+ W'_t \sqrt{1-\rho%2}$ is a brownian motion.
> - If $W_t$ is a Brownian motion then $X_t = \exp\left(\alpha W_t - \alpha^2t/2\right)$ is a martingale, where $\alpha$ is a fixed constant.

Any help is appreciated! As a recall, the conditions for a brownian motion are :

1. $W_0=0$
2. The sample path of $W$ is continuous and nowhere differentiable.
3. For $s\leqslant t$, $W_t-W_s$ is independent of all $W_u$ for $u\leqslant s$ and $W_t-W_s \sim N(0, t-s)$.

Comment: Please, post only [one question in one post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7132/290189).
Posting several questions in the same post is discouraged
and such questions may be put on hold, see [meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6464).

Comment: Perhaps a typo in your definition for Brownion motion $u \le s$ instead of $u \le t$

Answer (score 1):

The first one is clearly false because $(\sqrt t - \sqrt s) Z$ is not independent from $\sqrt s Z$. The second is also false because $E[X_t^2] = \rho^2 t + (1-\rho) t \neq t$. For the last it is correct and to prove it use the characteristic function of normal distribution variable.

Comment: thanks for you answer. Could you please clarify a little on the first one? Why are they not independent?

Comment: It is the same variable

Comment: okay yes I see it. How about the second one, I'm not sure why your argument works?

Comment: I am just computing the expectation of the square of $X_t$

Comment: Yes but how does that help proving or disproving the fact that it's a brownian motion?

Comment: If $X_t$ was a brownian motion, the value of $E(X_t^2) = t$

Comment: You made me realize I made a typo, sorry about that the second rho is squared actually.

Comment: In that case it will be a brownian motion