# Stochastic DEs.

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-differential-equations

If *X<sub>t</sub>* solves *dX<sub>t</sub> = μX<sub>t</sub> dt + σ dW<sub>t</sub>*, find the stochastic differential equation solved by:

1. X<sub>t</sub><sup>n</sup>, where *n* is a positive integer.
2. cos X<sub>t</sub>.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This is not an SPDE, it's an SDE (though one could argue that every SDE is an SPDE). The question is equivalent to asking you to differentiate $X^n_t$ and $\cos X_t$ by Ito's lemma.

Comment: So I solve it by using Ito's lemma?

Comment: How can you ask the present question and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2727051/) at the same time?

Comment: @Did What's the issue?

Comment: Context (lack of). Requisites (incoherent).

Comment: I really don't see the issue, parsiad was able to answer perfectly fine. What else should be specified? It's pretty straight-forward imo.

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(x)=x^{n}$ where $n>1$. Note that $f_{x}(x)=nx^{n-1}$ and $f_{xx}(x)=n(n-1)x^{n-2}$. By Ito's lemma,
\begin{align*}
d(X_{t}^{n}) & =f_{x}(X_{t})dX_{t}+\frac{1}{2}f_{xx}(X_{t}) dX_t^2\\
 & =nX_{t}^{n-1}\left(\mu X_{t}dt+\sigma dW_{t}\right)+\frac{1}{2}n\left(n-1\right)X_{t}^{n-2}\sigma^{2}dt\\
 & =\left(\mu nX_{t}^{n}+\frac{1}{2}\sigma^{2}n\left(n-1\right)X_{t}^{n-2}\right)dt+\left(\sigma nX_{t}^{n-1}\right)dW_{t}.
\end{align*}
This is an SDE satisfied by $(X^{n}_t)_{t\geq0}$.

Now, try the second question.

Comment: Great, thanks. I'll try and post what I get.

Comment: is dXt^2 always equal to sigma^2*dt? and if yes, why?

Comment: $dX^2$ is just an alternative way of writing $d[X,X]$, which is the evolution of the quadratic variation of $X$ (with respect to itself). You'll have to learn about quadratic variation if you want to understand this claim. Judging from your questions on Math.SE, it seems to me like you are missing or trying to skip the foundations and running into problems as a result.